VoiceOver UIAccessility.post(.announcement) interrupted by Apple alert
So I have a login screen, and when the user signs in it takes them to a new screen, I want VoiceOver to announce some prompt like "Welcome to the home screen" once the user gets there. But the issue is since I'm coming from a login screen, if I just get the destination view and add something like onAppear UIAccessibility.post it reads maybe half of the first word before Apple prompts to save the password in the keychain overriding the VoiceOver.
I also tried some mechanism where it tries to repeat until Apple posts that the announcement is complete, but this still is 1. glitchy and calls it around 3 times and 2. You'll hear a bit of the prompt at first and then again after you close the Apple system alert which gives a bad user experience
Any ideas?
